# Lifetime of function pointers

Tags: rust, lifetime

Why does the following program not compile:

```rust
pub struct Textbox<'a,VM> {
    get_element: Box<dyn Fn(VM)+'a>,
}

// Works
pub fn new<'a,VM,G:Fn(VM)+'a>(
    get_element: G,
) -> Textbox<'a,VM> {
    Textbox {
        get_element: Box::new(get_element),
    }
}

// Does not work. Compiler complains that we need
// a lifetime bound on VM.
// To the naive programmer writing this, it is unclear why,
// since the above function is accepted.
pub fn new_broken<'a,VM>(
    get_element: fn(VM),
) -> Textbox<'a,VM> {
    Textbox {
        get_element: Box::new(get_element),
    }
}
```

Why does the 'new' function compile, but not the 'new_broken'? What causes the requirement for specifying a lifetime on VM in 'new_broken' but not in 'new'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning an object with a generic lifetime somewhere along the function path, you have to state that `VM` lives at least as long as the object's generic lifetime.

By stating `G: Fn(VM) + 'a` you are inherently saying `VM: 'a` because the function cannot live longer than its parameters' types. In your new_broken function, you never put a restriction on `VM`'s lifetime so `VM` may not live as long as the returned `Textbox`.

Comment: _"because the function cannot live longer than its parameters"_ needs more elaboration. As currently phrased [it's not true](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dee7a2e03dd766176376c4eb83f24a82).

Comment: I believe that that's one of the instances where the static bound doesn't actually matter so is thrown out by the compiler. Whenever I try to use the "static-ness" of the function I'm forced to make sure A does not outlive the function: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=182a0f0d405b382bfd29f131dcb3223e)

Comment: Here is an instance where this occurs with any bound greater than a, not just static: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e312fd776c9f4afe185e233ee9a988d)